# httpAdditionalHeaders not working on linux

Tags: linux, swift, ibm-cloud, foundation, kitura

I ran into a problem of different behaviour of URLSession / URLSessionConfiguration / URLSessionDataTask on OS X and Linux.

Swift: 3.0.2
Kitura: 1.3

I am doing following:

```
let aURL = URL(string: "...")!

// Because shared is not implemented                
let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default

sessionConfig.httpAdditionalHeaders = ["Accept": "application/json", "Accept-Language": "sv-SE"]

let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig)

// additionalHeaders are set just fine                
Log.info("\(session.configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders)")

let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: aURL, completionHandler: { data, loadResponse, error in
                   ...
                })

 dataTask.resume()
```

The additional headers are set on the configuration object, but when deployed to Bluemix the response show that language header field is missing (i get the response in wrong language).

I know that the request is correct because when I build and run this (Kitura) locally (thorough Xcode on OS X) I get the expected behaviour.

Has anyone encountered this? What to do? Where to go?

Comment: This issue is fixed. https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3463 Pull request:https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/pull/927

Answer (score 2):

This could've been a comment, but I am still not allowed to post comments!

Yes, my colleague came across this while working on [this bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2617). I think the work-around that you adopted is the best alternative option. This needs more investigation. I have created a [new bug report](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3463) report for this issue.

Comment: Thanks for this, I was hit by what seems to be the same (the work-around didn't solve it for me - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41601863/urlsession-on-linux-giving-different-result-than-on-ios ). I made sure to up-vote your bug report, hope others do the same

Answer (score 0):

Found a hackaround myself doing:

```
...
var request = URLRequest(url: aURL, cachePolicy: .reloadRevalidatingCacheData, timeoutInterval: 3)
request.setValue("sv-SE", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept-Language")
let dataTask = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default).dataTask(with: request, ...
```

Even though it works it would be nice to know what is going on with the original solution, because I like it better (it's prettier).

Is it a bug in Foundation on linux?

Edit: Workaround seems to only work in Swift 3.0.2, it doesn't work in 3.0.1. Something is really funky with URL headers.