# URLSession on Linux giving different result than on iOS

Tags: swift, swift3, server-side, urlrequest

I've got [a simple class](https://github.com/niklassaers/SO_UrlsessionTest/blob/master/Sources/urlsessionTest.swift) making a HTTP POST request (to a Neo4j server, but that shouldn't matter) using URLSession, and [an integration test](https://github.com/niklassaers/SO_UrlsessionTest/blob/master/Tests/urlsessionTestTests/urlsessionTestTests.swift) that tests that it succeeds.

Through Xcode, via the iOS simulator, I can run this test a million times - it succeeds every time.

However, when I run `swift test` on Ubuntu Linux (I use [the docker image provided by IBM](https://github.com/IBM-Swift/swift-ubuntu-docker)) then I very often will get a test failure saying I got a 401 response.

[Replicating that via cURL](https://github.com/niklassaers/SO_UrlsessionTest/blob/master/curl-request.sh) in the container does not fail at all, so I do not believe this to be a problem with my container.

I have added a [packet dump](https://github.com/niklassaers/SO_UrlsessionTest/blob/master/example.pcap) (that I inspect via [Charles Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com)) where our of 15 test runs, 7 test runs (and thus 7 requests) fail. All of the failed requests complain that no authentication header was supplied. And from the dump, that is correct, the dump does not contain the authentication header for those requests that fail. But why not? In fact, all of the header flags are different: a successful run has these headers:

```
POST /db/data/cypher HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.0.18:7474
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
Authorization: Basic bmVvNGo6c3RhY2swdmVyRmxvdw==
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Accept: application/json; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: urlsessionTestPackageTests.xctest (unknown version) curl/7.35.0
Content-Length: 135
```

while an unsuccessful one has these:

```
POST /db/data/cypher HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.0.18:7474
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: urlsessionTestPackageTests.xctest (unknown version) curl/7.35.0
Content-Length: 135
```

All the 200 results have the same headers, and all the 401 results have the same headers. Can you see anything in [my code](https://github.com/niklassaers/SO_UrlsessionTest/blob/master/Sources/urlsessionTest.swift) that should warrant such a random request?

Comment: Seems similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41229814/httpadditionalheaders-not-working-on-linux - the container Swift version is 3.0.1

Comment: I updated to Swift 3.0.2, still same error. So I adjusted the code as suggested above, and got only 5 errors out of 62 requests. Much better, but it still fails and I still don't know why.

Comment: Issue persists with the now official Docker image with 16.04: https://github.com/swiftdocker/docker-swift